# Ionic React-Hook-Forms

Tags: reactjs, forms, ionic-framework, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Trying to use Ionic React Hook Forms, could anyone help me with the below questions

1. Trying to build forms dynamically, how can we pass the properties of the ion element dynamically. in the below example i want to pass maxlength and text property (coming from backend / formFields) to IonInput Element
2. How to pre-populate the value to the input field

Form.tsx

```
    import {
      IonContent,
      IonPage,
      IonText,
      IonButton,
    } from "@ionic/react";
    import React from "react";
    import "./Form.css";
    import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
    import * as globalStructre from "../Components/Content";
    import Input from "../Components/Input";
    import Date from "../Components/Date";
    import Select from "../Components/Select";
    import Textarea from "../Components/Textarea";
    import Toggle from "../Components/Toggle";
                
                const Form: React.FC = () => {
                  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
                
                  const formFields: globalStructre.IngressProps[] = [
                    {
                      type: "Input",
                      name: "email",
                      component: ['type=\'email\''],
                      label: "Email",
                      value: "",
                    },
                    {
                      type: "Input",
                      name: "fullName",
                      component: ['maxlength = 60', 'type=\'text\''], //properties
                      label: "Full Name",
                      value: "test",
                    },
                    {
                      type: "Input",
                      name: "password",
                      component: ['maxlength = 12', 'type=\'password\''],
                      label: "Password",
                      value: "",
                    },
                  ];
                
                  const registerUser = (data: any) => {
                    console.log("creating a new user account with: ", data);
                  };
                
                  const buildForm = (field: globalStructre.IngressProps, key: any) => {
                    let inputElement = null;
                    switch (field.type) {
                      case "Input":
                        inputElement = (
                          <Input
                            key={key}
                            name={field.name}
                            control={control}
                            component={field.component}
                            value={field.value}
                            label={field.label}
                            rules={field.rules}
                          />
                        );
                        break;
                    }
                
                    return inputElement;
                  };
                
                  return (
                    <IonPage>
                      <IonContent>
                        <div className="ion-padding">
                          <IonText color="muted">
                            <h2>Create Account</h2>
                          </IonText>
                          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(registerUser)}>
                            {formFields.map((field, index) =>
                              //<Input {...field} control={control} key={index} />
                              buildForm(field, index)
                            )}
                            <IonButton expand="block" type="submit" className="ion-margin-top">
                              Register
                            </IonButton>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </IonContent>
                    </IonPage>
                  );
                };
                
                export default Form;
```

Input.tsx

```
    import React, { FC } from "react";
    import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonInput, IonText } from "@ionic/react";
    import { Controller} from "react-hook-form";
    import * as globalStructre from './Content';
    import './Input.css';
    
    const Input: FC<globalStructre.IngressProps> = ({
      key,
      name,
      control,
      component,
      value,
      label,
      rules,
      errors,
    }) => {
     
      return (
        <>
          <IonItem >
            {label && <IonLabel position="floating">{label}</IonLabel>}
            <Controller
              render = {({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (          
              <IonInput
                key={key}
                value ={value}
                onIonChange={onChange}
              />
              )}
              name={name}
              control={control}
              rules = {rules}
            />
          </IonItem>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Input;
```

Comment: do you have a project somewhere to use as a starting point?

Comment: got it fixed using a object instead of array.                                                      
               <IonInput
                key={key}
                value ={value}
                onIonChange={onChange} {...component}
              />